# Get Median Value of an Array's key

Tags: php, arrays

How can this function be used to return the median of the keys in an array?

```
function array_median($array) {
  $iCount = count($array);
  $middle_index = floor($iCount / 2);
  sort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
  $median = $array[$middle_index];
  if ($iCount % 2 == 0) {
    $median = ($median + $array[$middle_index - 1]) / 2;
  }
  return $median;
}
```

With an array like this:
`$arr = array('5'=>100,'1'=>30,'2'=>80);`

The median value should be key `2`.

Comment: _"The median value should be key 2"_ ...and? Almost 2k reputation, we should be needing to link you [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @FirstOne Was trying to explain the expected outcome.

Comment: I got that xD. But what are you getting? I mean, if not the expected, what's being returned?

Comment: I need to get the median value of the key in an array to then sort it...I don't need help with the sorting just the key. It will give me a variation in the data when I process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get median key, You need to calculate median for keys instead of values.

```
function array_median($array) {
  // get keys of passed array
  $array = array_keys($array);
  $iCount = count($array);
  $middle_index = floor($iCount / 2);
  sort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
  $median = $array[$middle_index];
  if ($iCount % 2 == 0) {
    $median = ($median + $array[$middle_index - 1]) / 2;
  }
  return $median;
}

$arr = array('5'=>100,'1'=>30,'2'=>80);
echo array_median($arr);  // output 2
```

Comment: Thats makes absolutely ZERO difference. `count(array_keys($array))` === `count($array)` _Think about it_

Comment: yes, but its not about the count, its about the array values.

Comment: @RiggsFolly `count(array_keys($array))` doesn't return the median.

Comment: @RavinderReddy Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, but it doesn't base the calculation on the `key` but the `value`. If you change the value to `'2'=>150`, `'5'` will be the median value.